# java program in xscreensaver

Tags: java, screensaver, xscreensaver

Trying to run my Java Swing program in xscreensaver.
The program runs great from command line. It uses the whole screen with

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

`Added to xscreensaver setup:`

/usr/bin/java -jar "$HOME/java/clock/target/clock-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

`
When kicked in, xscreensaver shows black screen.
When I click a button to stop screensaver, it shows my program screen for a moment, then I see the regular screen.
Using Ubuntu 20.04.6, xscreensaver 5.42.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious as to how you got this to work at all. I thought xscreensaver hacks required using the X11 window ID passed in $XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW. I've never found a way to get Java to draw into the hack window.

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you call "hack window". Take a look at my code snapshot, I obtain GraphicsDevice and attach frame to it.

Comment: It's pretty well described here: https://github.com/Zygo/xscreensaver/blob/master/README.hacking

I suppose both the xscreensaver window is running, but somehow the "Visual: Best" allows the JFrame to display over the top of it. I'll have to try this when I get a chance!

Answer (score 0):

In xscreensaver-demo, selecting my script, going to Settings, Advanced, selecting

```
Visual: Best
```

resolves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use the window ID to accomplish this. Though this repo is in Clojure, it should be easy enough to re-create in Java. The approach is documented in the README.

https://github.com/robbieh/clj-xscreensaver-basic-demo